# Django unable to persisted cached array

Tags: django

Django cannot persist my cached data even if I set timeout to none.

My settings.py contains this:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'django_cache', #'/var/tmp/django_cache',
        'TIMEOUT': None,
    }
}
```

I save data with this line of code:

```
cache.set('array', array, timeout=None)
```

I fetch data like this:

```
array = cache.get('array')
        
try:
     iterator = iter(array)
except TypeError:
     # Array not iterable: my app gets here when cache data is lost
else:
     # I go through the array and get needed info
```

I don't think it's a MAX_ENTRIES issue because I only have one array with 39 elements.

When the data is lost, the array becomes not iterable (because empty).

I also tried using file cache cause I suspected that restarting the Django app may clear the RAM cache but had the same issue.

I've tried file caching with the following configuration in settings.py:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'filecache'),
        'TIMEOUT': None,
    }
}
```

The "filecache" directory is created and contains a non-empty cache file but I still loose my cached array somehow.

Comment: What does array contain? Can you share the code that populates it?

Comment: It's a 1 dimension array containing 41 objects in this shape:
{val: "000", text: "some text", label: "some label"}

Comment: When you say array do you mean a list or something else? Can you share the code the populates this array

Comment: A list of objects, sorry I cannot share the full code because I get the list from a WebService then I process it. I declare my array with array = [] then I append elements to it with array.append({"val": val, "text": text, "label": label}). At the end I sort the elements inside it with array = sorted(array, key=itemgetter('val')).

Comment: The list is accessible from cache for an amount of time then it disappears.

Comment: How is your application deployed/running?

Comment: with python manage.py runserver in a virtualenv environment on Windows Server 2016.